# Connection timed out :connect error while downloading from Nexus in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, nexus, maven-dependency-plugin

I want only single command to download from Nexus. I also tried using copy goal instead of get.

I am using the following command to download from Nexus:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:get -DremoteRepositories=url  -Dartifact=groupId:ArtifactId:Version -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

But i am getting a timeout error and trying to download from central, not from my remote repository.

What changes do i need to do in `settings.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

See here for instructions on setting up Maven to work with Nexus Repo:  https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Maven+Repositories#MavenRepositories-ConfiguringApacheMaven

Answer (score 0):

check whether your network/firewall is blocking such request, there is a high possibility of firewall blocking access of maven repository location. 
generic setting.xml looks like,

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository/>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <usePluginRegistry/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>
  <servers/>
  <mirrors/>
  <proxies/>
  <profiles/>
  <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

Check MAVEN_HOME and M2_HOME in enviroment variable of setup of your local machine's maven home